# Empty Electron window when debugging Typescript app in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, electron

I am trying to debug a typescript application in Visual Studio Code (vs code) which uses Electron - a terminal emulator [Black-Screen](https://github.com/shockone/black-screen).

I am attempting to do this by launching my application from in vs code. The breakpoint points I set in the main Typescript application file [src/main/Main.ts](https://github.com/shockone/black-screen/blob/master/src/main/Main.ts) are breaking as expected & and I can inspect variable values.

Electron is also launching, however the Black-Screen application doesn't load in Electron (I only see an emtpy Electron window). See screenshot of empty Electron window.

[image]

I can transpile the application using the typescript-compiler (tsc) and no errors are generated, and can see the compiled javascript in the folder I expect (src/bin/). I can also start the application successfully using npm ("npm start").

Below are the relevant project configuration files:

1. src/tsconfig.json

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es6",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "preserveConstEnums": true,
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "noEmitOnError": true,
       "pretty": true,
       "jsx": "react",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "outDir": "bin"
     }
   }
   ```
2. .vscode/tasks.json file
   Note. Executing the equivalent command in a terminal "tsc --project src" generates the transpiled js code with no errors or warnings.

   ```
   {
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "command": "tsc",
       "isShellCommand": true,
       "showOutput": "silent",
       "args": ["--project", "src"],
       "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
   }
   ```
3. .vscode/launch.json

   ```
   {
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
       {
         "name": "Launch Black-Screen",
         "type": "node",
         "request": "launch",
         "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main/Main.ts",
         "stopOnEntry": false,
         "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
         "sourceMaps": true,
         "externalConsole": false,
         "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/src/bin",
         "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron",
         // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
         "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
         // Environment variables passed to the program.
         "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   Note. The launch.json configuration generates the command-line statement in the debug console:
   `/home/michael/development/black-screen/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron --debug-brk=3323 --nolazy src/bin/main/Main.js`.

See screenshot of debug console.
[image]

Hopefully someone has come across a similar issue with vs code and Electron and can assist :)

Answer (score 1):

First it would be preferable if you use

```
"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron"
```

If you develop on Windows or OS X, you'll get in trouble as you then have to use the executable file of each env.

That said Electron requires that the `outDir` of your app is relative to `resources/app`. http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-distribution/